# Doctrine 2 Inheritance Mapping with Association

Tags: php, inheritance, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

**NOTE : if what I want is not possible, a "not possible" answer will be accepted**

In the [Doctrine 2 documentation about **inheritance mapping**](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html), it says there are 2 ways :

- Single table inheritance (STI)
- Class table inheritance (CTI)

For both, there is the warning :

> If you use a STI/CTI entity as a many-to-one or one-to-one entity **you should never use one of the classes at the upper levels** of the inheritance hierachy as “targetEntity”, only those that have no subclasses. Otherwise Doctrine CANNOT create proxy instances of this entity and will ALWAYS load the entity eagerly.

So, how can I proceed **to use inheritance with an association to the base (abstract) class** ? (and keep the performance of course)

---

### Example

A user has many `Pet` (abstract class extended by `Dog` or `Cat`).

What I want to do :

```
class User {
    /**
     * @var array(Pet) (array of Dog or Cat)
     */
    private $pets;
}
```

Because of the warning in Doctrine documentation, I should do that :

```
class User {
    /**
     * @var array(Dog)
     */
    private $dogs;
    /**
     * @var array(Cat)
     */
    private $cats;
}
```

**This is annoying, because I loose the benefits of inheritance !**

*Note : I didn't add the Doctrine annotations for the mapping to DB, but you can understand what I mean*

Comment: good question, you probably have to target dogs and cats spereratly

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I want to do :p

Comment: same here :-/  I've the same situation with nodes (pages / posts / stuff) and comments

Comment: Remember it is just a warning. I ignored this warning cause it looks like there is no solution for it. I accepted that in these cases it will not load the proxies. Just a choice between technical overview and performance. I choose the first... But still curious if there is a solution for this somewhere.

Comment: I must be missing something, but I'd love to help you. Can you possibly expand on your question to include examples of what you *want* to do vs. what you feel like you *have* to do? As the question is written now it seems like it would require someone to be in the same mindset as a typical Doctrine user, which I am not :)

Comment: I extended the example to be clearer, let me know if that's better. Thanks

Comment: why can't you just add a method getPets that will merge dogs and cats and return them?

Comment: That's not a bad idea, though it's some work that inheritance is supposed to handle :(. And if I want to add pets, I have to have some switch or ifs with `instanceof`... Lot's of weird stuff for such a simple thing. I'll keep that in mind if no solution comes up.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I'm tired, but this seems like much ado about nothing.

You missed the important bit of that warning:

> If you use a STI/CTI entity **as a many-to-one or one-to-one entity**

That's not the case in your example!  If you had not omitted the doctrine annotations, you might have noticed.

The association User::pets is OneToMany, not [One|Many]ToOne.  One user has many pets.

The inverse association **is** OneToOne, but it's targeting User, which has no inheritance.

Robin's answer should have been a good hint -- you can log the sql queries and see what doctrine actually does to  your database!

---

The bad-for-performance scenario is something like:

```
abstract class Pet { ... }

class Cat extends Pet { ... } 

class Dog extends Pet { ... }

class Collar {
   /**
    * @Column(length="16")
    */

   protected $color;
   /**
    * ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pet")
    */
   protected $owner;
}
```

Now, if you wanted to iterate over all the blue collars, Doctrine runs into some trouble.  It doesn't know what class $owner is going to be, so it can't use a Proxy.  Instead, it's forced to eagerly load $owner to find out whether it's a Cat or a Dog.

This isn't a problem for OneToMany or ManyToMany relationships, because in that case, lazy loading works fine.  Instead of a proxy, you get a PersistentCollection.  And a PersistentCollection is always just a PersistentCollection.  It doesn't care about it's own contents until you actually ask for them.  So lazy loading works fine.

Comment: Oh! Well congrats for clarifying that, if you are indeed right (it seems so, I'v re-read the doctrine documentation and you seem to be right), then the problem is solved!

Comment: @timdev You say "_if you wanted to iterate over all the blue collars_". Is the "blue" part important? Does the problem disappear if I just want to iterate over **all** collars?

Comment: I would like to add, that if your owning side of the User::pets is ```OneToMany```, you should use the ```ManyToOne``` annotation on the inverse side. You are 'talking' about the inverse side of the Entity, not the current relation of the Entity.

Answer (score 46):

I think you've misunderstood, the section of the manual you've quoted is entitled "Performance impact", they're not telling you you *can't* do this, only that there are performance implications if you do.  This makes sense for lazy loading - for heterogeneous collections of STI entities you have to go to the database and load the entity before you know what class it will be, so lazy loading isn't possible / doesn't make sense.  I'm learning Doctrine 2 myself at the moment, so I mocked up your example, the following works OK for more:

```
namespace Entities;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="pets")
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="pet_type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"cat" = "Cat", "dog" = "Dog"})
 */
class Pet
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @generatedValue */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string", length=300) */
    private $name;

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="id") */
    private $owner;
}


/** @Entity */
class Dog extends Pet
{

    /** @Column(type="string", length=50) */
    private $kennels;
}

/** @Entity */
class Cat extends Pet
{
    /** @Column(type="string", length=50) */
    private $cattery;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @generatedValue */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(length=255, nullable=false) */
    private $name;


    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Pet", mappedBy="owner") */
    private $pets;
}
```

... and the test script ....

```
if (false) {
    $u = new Entities\User;
    $u->setName("Robin");

    $p = new Entities\Cat($u, 'Socks');
    $p2 = new Entities\Dog($u, 'Rover');

    $em->persist($u);
    $em->persist($p);
    $em->persist($p2);
    $em->flush();
} else if (true) {
    $u = $em->find('Entities\User', 1);
    foreach ($u->getPets() as $p) {
        printf("User %s has a pet type %s called %s\n", $u->getName(), get_class($p), $p->getName());
    }
} else {
    echo "  [1]\n";
    $p = $em->find('Entities\Cat', 2);
    echo "  [2]\n";
    printf("Pet %s has an owner called %s\n", $p->getName(), $p->getOwner()->getName());
}
```

All my cats and dogs load as the correct type:

If you look at the generated SQL, you'll notice that when the OneToMany targetEntity is "pet", you get SQL like this:

```
SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.owner_id AS owner_id3, pet_type, 
t0.cattery AS cattery4, t0.kennels AS kennels5 FROM pets t0 
WHERE t0.owner_id = ? AND t0.pet_type IN ('cat', 'dog')
```

But when it's set to Cat, you get this:

```
SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.cattery AS cattery3, t0.owner_id 
AS owner_id4, pet_type FROM pets t0 WHERE t0.owner_id = ? AND t0.pet_type IN ('cat')
```

HTH.

Comment: I see what you mean, but performance is a great deal. I'm wondering what should I do to still take advantage of inheritance and don't suffer from the performance impact. If that's not possible (for now, or for ever with Doctrine), I want to see it written black on white because it doesn't seem obvious to me. That would be an answer to my question. What the doc is saying is : with that solution, you can't if you want to keep performance. But is there any way to go around that ?

Comment: My question is still open even though the bounty is closed

Comment: To everyone, see timdev's answer, very interesting.

Comment: @Robin : Looking at your code how is the attribute `inversedBy="id"` in your Pet class suppose to work? This would throw a Doctrine error: "...refers to the inverse side field Entity\User#id which is not defined as association.".

Comment: @webDEVILopers It's a long time since I wrote this answer, perhaps Doctrine has changed subtly since.  Either way, I don't remember exactly how this works!

Comment: Thanks @Robin. I just wondered if you found a magic way to use inheritance with an association to the base (abstract) class. Because I could not make it work.