# Doctrine 2 Concrete Table Inheritance with Associations

Tags: php, inheritance, orm, doctrine-orm, concrete-inheritance

I have read [Doctrine 2 Inheritance Mapping with Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715777/doctrine-2-inheritance-mapping-with-association) but say if you needed `Animal` to be an entity in its own right, say for creating option lists.

In this case the Discriminator Column for a `Pet` is in the species column in the `animal table`.

[image: Pet Database Schema]

So the classes would be something like this.

```
class Animal
{
    $id;
    $species;
}

/**
 * @Table(name="animal")
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="species", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"dog" = "Dog", "cat" = "Cat"})
 */
abstract class Pet
{
    $id
    $species;
}

class Dog extends Pet { }

class Cat extends Pet { }

class Owner 
{
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Pet")
     */
    $pets
}
```

I see a couple of problems.

1. the `animal` table doesn't have a foreign key to `owner`. So the the
   `$pets` association isn't going to work.
2. `Animal` and `Pet` are more or less that same thing. If some one
   changes something in `Animal` those changes wouldn't be reflected in
   any `Pet` subclasses.

A possible solution to the first problem would be to have an extra table called `pet`, but there is still an issue with the association, because the discriminator column is still in the `animal` table and duplicating the column in `pet` would break normalisation.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure to fully understand your problem, but I'll give it a try:

- A `Pet` being an `Animal`, it makes sense to **make it explicit in your class hierarchy**. Note that the *abstract* class `Pet` can subclass the *concrete* class `Animal`. This way, you can still instantiate an `Animal`, a `Dog` or a `Cat`, but you can't instantiate a `Pet`;
- The `Animal` root class can have **its own discriminator value**, which makes possible to persist it with Doctrine. You can then create and persist a `Dog` or a `Cat`, and even a generic `Animal`;
- `Animal` needs **a reference to its owner**;
- `Owner` now has a **one-to-many relationship** to `Animal`;
- The `species` column is a discriminator, and adds **no value to your domain model** (the class name will tell you which `Animal` you're dealing with), so I would advise to remove this property.

Final note, do you really need a `Pet` class? If a Pet has nothing specific over an `Animal` (i.e. the class is empty), then you should probably remove it from your class hierarchy.

```
class Owner {
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Animal")
     */
    protected $animals;
}

/**
 * @Table(name="animal")
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="species", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"animal" = "Animal", "dog" = "Dog", "cat" = "Cat"})
 */
class Animal {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    protected $id;

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Owner") */
    protected $owner;
}

abstract class Pet extends Animal {
    // Do you really need this class?
}

class Dog extends Pet {
    // ...
}

class Cat extends Pet {
    // ...
}
```

About your database structure, I propose the following changes:

- Move `owner_id` from `Dog` & `Cat` to the `Animal` table;
- Remove `animal_id` from the `Dog` & `Cat` tables; they'll share the `id` value with the `Animal` table (*one-to-one*).