# Doctrine ORM - Same entity, different table for different ownership

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I have an entity that in it's lifetime moves to different tables. Like so:

A village has many units
An army movement on the map contains many units
After an attack, the log file contains many units (with extra `amount_killed` column)

So anyway, this `Unit` is what I consider my entity, that can either be attached to a Village, Movement or Log via a table and foreign key.

I would think in Doctrine there is a way to say, this is an entity and it can as a foreign key to multiple tables. The thing is, I want to pluck Units from my Village and put them into a Movement but they're not defined as the same item so it will break.

My code for current usage will look something like this for transferring an entity to another table:

```
$villageUnits = $village->getVillageUnits();
$movementUnits = new ArrayCollection();
foreach ($villageUnits as $villageUnit) {
    $movementUnit = new MovementUnit();
    $movementUnit
        ->setLevel($villageUnit->getLevel());
        ->setAmount($villageUnit->getAmount());
        ->setUnitType($villageUnit->getUnitType());
    $movementUnits->add($movementUnit);
}
```

At the moment, they're all seperate entities defined with Doctrine as follows:

```
TABLES

village_units
---------
id, village_id, unit_type_id, amount, level

movement_units
---------
id, movement_id, unit_type_id, amount, level

log_units
---------
id, log_id, unit_type_id, amount, amount_killed, level


ENTITIES

/**
 * MovementUnit
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="movement_units")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MovementUnit
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $amount;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="level", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $level;

/**
 * @var Movement
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Movement")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="movement_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $movement;

/**
 * @var UnitType
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UnitType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="unit_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $unitType;

}

/**
 * VillageUnit
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="village_units")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class VillageUnit
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $amount;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="level", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $level;

/**
 * @var Village
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Village")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="village_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $village;

/**
 * @var UnitType
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UnitType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="unit_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $unitType;

}

/**
 * LogUnit
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="log_units")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class LogUnit
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $amount;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dead", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $dead;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="level", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $level;

/**
 * @var LogArmy
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="LogArmy")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="log_army_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $logArmy;

/**
 * @var UnitType
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UnitType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="unit_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $unitType;

}
```

Comment: I have exactly the same question. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and solved it with the answer of Robin in this question: [Doctrine 2 Inheritance Mapping with Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715777/doctrine-2-inheritance-mapping-with-association)

Just change the inheritanceType from "SINGLE_TABLE" to "JOINED" and your setup is working. If not, try using doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create it will create the tables for you.